# Много кнопок и одно событие

Tags: javascript

Ситуация такова, есть есть несколько карточек товара с функцией добавлениях в корзину

собственно и всё
как повесить одно событие на каждую кнопку?

Answer (score 1):

Вам может помочь всплытие событий. При наступлении события обработчики сначала срабатывают на самом вложенном элементе, затем на его родителе, затем выше и так далее, вверх по цепочке вложенности. [детальнее](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling)

соответственно можно сделать что то подобное

```js
const handler = event => alert(event.target.name)
```

```html
<div onclick="handler(event)">
  <button name="one">one</button>
  <button name="two">two</button>
  <button name="three">three</button>
</div>
```

При таком подходе Вы можете добавлять сколько угодно кнопок (товаров) которые не будут ничего знать о том как их обрабатывают